# Missing folder in right-click nautilus menu

Tags: nautilus

Missing default "Downloads" folder in right-click nautilus menu. But it exists in the nautilus. How to add it?

[image: Right-click menu]
[image: Nautilus]

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu system at hand, could you please upload your `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop` file to a pastebin and notify me then?

Comment: @ByteCommander http://pastebin.com/EgeKx3i4